# how to Parse Query search case insensitive in android?

Tags: android, search, parse-platform

I am using the parse cloud to store data .
in this case I have a table "MyUser" in this table I want to search user by name in case insensitive.

**Search is working fine but the search operation is not case insensitive**

**I have to search case insensitive**

here is my code.:-

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("BetsUpUser");
query.whereContains("name", searchData);
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
     public void done(List<ParseObject> objList,ParseException e) {
       if (e == null) {
          Log.d("score","@@@@Retrieved " + objList.size()+ " scores");

       } else {
          Log.d("score", "@@@Error: " + e.getMessage());
       }
    }
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I Solve the problem of case insensitive string Parse Query

**replace the line**

```
query.whereContains("name", searchData);
```

**with**

```
query.whereMatches("name", "("+searchData+")", "i");
```

Comment: this won't scale.  as your data grows, this will get slow and eventually time-out and stop working entirely.

Comment: approximately after how much data will the issue start coming ?

Comment: @VihaanVerma approx 5000

Answer (score 2):

I also came across with this question and realized there are no much ways to do this simple thing. [Another interesting approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18764158/3810333) from @ardrian by using `JavaScript`. For `Java` it will almost the same. He suggests to create one more field with lowercase version of the searchable one. It look like below:

```
ParseObject gameScore = new ParseObject("BetsUpUser");
gameScore.put("name", name);
gameScore.put("name_lowercase", name.toLowerCase());
gameScore.saveInBackground();
```

And while searching we transform input text to lower case. This way we still can use `whereContains()` method and it will not affect us much.

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("BetsUpUser");
query.whereContains("name_lowercase", searchData.toLowerCase()); // the only one change
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
     public void done(List<ParseObject> objList,ParseException e) {
       if (e == null) {
          Log.d("ParseQuery", objList.get(0).get("name"));//name in actual case
       } else {
          Log.d("ParseQuery", e.getMessage());
       }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

See this post on the Parse Blog about implementing scalable search.

http://blog.parse.com/2013/03/19/implementing-scalable-search-on-a-nosql-backend/

Basically you can use an afterSave event to save a searchable field (i.e. lower-cased name) on the object.

Comment: in this blog it is for ios I have it in android

Comment: the blog post is Cloud Code and is to give you an idea..  the three-line iOS example at the end is something you already know how to do in Android.