# Facing an issue when applying a search on pointer column - Parse Opensource - Cloud Function

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server, back4app, parse-cloud-code

I have an two tables:-

Countries
Customers [have a number of column- ike name, address, city, zipcode, email, etc]
Customer table have an column country [Pointer of Countries].

Now what I want: I have a search form and if some put "aus" in a search box and click on "Search" button I want to display all matching records, I want to apply search on "Name, email, address, city, and the Country name [pointer]"

So if someone has name Austin or Country name "Australia" will be the output of search, currently, I'm using "contains" on the name, email and it is working fine.

I tried to apply search on country but not successes, could someone please help to apply this.

Here is my current code that is working [Without Country search], I am using cloud functions.

```
`var customerName = new Parse.Query("customer");
  var customerEmail = new Parse.Query("customer");
  var customerAddress = new Parse.Query("customer");
  customerName.contains('name','aus');
  customerEmail.contains('email','aus');
  customerAddress.contains('address','aus');

 var serviceQuery = new Parse.Query.or(
      customerName,
      customerEmail,
      customerAddress
      // country
  );
```

.............`
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
var customerName = new Parse.Query('customer');
var customerEmail = new Parse.Query('customer');
var customerAddress = new Parse.Query('customer');
customerName.contains('name','aus');
customerEmail.contains('email','aus');
customerAddress.contains('address','aus');

var countryQuery = new Parse.Query('country');
countryQuery.contains('name','aus');
var customerCountry = new Parse.Query('customer');
customerCountry.matchesQuery('country', countryQuery);

var serviceQuery = new Parse.Query.or(
  customerName,
  customerEmail,
  customerAddress,
  customerCountry
);
```

Instead of searching for each of customers' fields, you can use full text search:
https://docs.parseplatform.org/js/guide/#full-text-search

Comment: Thanks for the reply but it returning 0 objects

Comment: Actually the issue is due to Capital letter. Can we ignor uppercase and lowercase check while search?

Comment: @KishorPatidar Yes, you can ignore case - see:https://stackoverflow.com/a/35209613/487873

Comment: Thanks solution is working I changed **countryQuery.contains('name','aus');** with **countryQuery.matches('name','aus', 'i');** and it is ** working**.

Answer (score 0):

A solution would be to compute a `fullTextSearch` field on cloud `beforeSave` of your objects. The best way is to store this string in lowercase and without diacritics. It will give better results if you do the same when searching (so that `André` will match `andre` or `AnDrÉ`).

Here is the helper I used to do so:

```js
  /**
   * Generates fulltextsearch for any Parse.Object. It's the concatenation of the value
   * of all fields in propertiesToAdd, separated by a whitespace and lowercased.
   * Often used in beforeSave :)
   * @param propertiesToAdd the list of the object properties names that we want to handle in fulltextsearch
   * @param newObject the new version of the object
   */
  static generateFulltextSearch(propertiesToAdd, newObject): string {
    let result = '';
    propertiesToAdd.forEach(property => {
      let value = newObject.get(property);
      if (value) {
        result += DiacriticRemove(value) + ' ';
      }
    });

    return result.trim().toLocaleLowerCase();
  }
```

`DiacriticRemove` is simply a call to [Diacritics package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/diacritics).

In your `beforeSave` (in cloud code), you just have to call:

```js
  myCustomer("myFullTextField", generateFulltextSearch(["name", "email", "address", "country", "anyotherField"], myCustomer))
```

Then, when you're searching:

```js
var customer = new Parse.Query("customer");
// Don't forget to lowercase and remove diacritics from your searched string.
customer.contains('myFullTextField','aus');
```

And voilà :)